# How to store checkbox values (laravel)

Tags: laravel-5.4

I have List of the infraction and All infraction is print in a foreach loop. I want to store some infraction id in the database using checkbox.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    @foreach($infractions as $infraction)
       <tr>
           <th>{{ $infraction->title }}</th>
           <td>
               <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $infraction->id }}" name="infraction_id[{{ $infraction->id }}]" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
           </td>
       </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

I have no idea where I put submit button and how to get value from a checkbox into Controller to save data.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request['infraction_id']!= null){
        foreach ($request['infraction_id'] as $inf){
            $query="insert into inspection ('title') value ($infraction->id)";
        }
    }
    auth()->user()->inspections()->create($request->all());
}
```

I want to change php (a example) to laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Change chceckbox name to

```
name=infraction_id[]
```